# Query to Select Number of Rows (Posts) that Match all Post Meta Fields in Condition Statement

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm using the free version of YITH Woocommerce Subscriptions to allow users of my Wordpress site the ability to purchase products on a subscription basis. When a user purchases a subscription several things happen. A new post is created for the order, a new subscription is created for the order and both the order and the subscription have various post meta added to them. I am concerned about checking whether or not a user has an active subscription for a certain product of mine with the product id "432".

Here's an example of the records in the database:

**post_meta table**

```
post_id: 468
meta_key: _product_id
meta_value: 432

post_id: 468
meta_key: _user_id
meta_value: 1

post_id: 468
meta_key: _status
meta_value: active
```

The example above shows that user with the ID "1" has an "active" subscription which is subscription "468" for the product "432".

I'm not sure how to form a query that will check that the current logged in user has an active subscription to product 432 because the data is not stored in a single row.

---

**EDIT:** With James's answer I was able to update my query and get the below result. However, I am not able to run a successful where/having clause. When I add a where or having clause, the query returns empty.

**NEW QUERY:**

```
SELECT post_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(meta_key='_product_id', meta_value,'') SEPARATOR '') product_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(meta_key='_status', meta_value,'') SEPARATOR '') status,
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(meta_key='_user_id', meta_value,'') SEPARATOR '') user
FROM wprq_postmeta
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY post_id DESC
```

**RESULTS:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
           [post_id] => 471
           [product_id] =>
           [status] =>
           [user] =>
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
           [post_id] => 468
           [product_id] => 432
           [status] => active
           [user] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
           [post_id] => 465
           [product_id] => 432
           [status] => active
           [user] => 2
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
           [post_id] => 499
           [product_id] =>
           [status] =>
           [user] =>
        )
)
```

In the above result set, I only want the result where "**status = 'active' AND product_id = 432 AND user = 1**"

---

**EDIT 2:** I think the position of my having clause mattered. I originally had my having clause before my group by clause and I was getting an empty result set. When I moved my having clause after my group by clause it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of James I was able to get the following query to work. I did not realize the placement of my HAVING clause had to be after my GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT post_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(meta_key='_product_id', meta_value,'') SEPARATOR '') product_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(meta_key='_status', meta_value,'') SEPARATOR '') status,
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(meta_key='_user_id', meta_value,'') SEPARATOR '') user
FROM wprq_postmeta
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING product_id = 432 AND status = 'active' AND user = $user
ORDER BY post_id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach, let me know if you have any local issues,

```
CREATE TABLE post_meta(post_id INT, meta_key CHAR(32), meta_value CHAR(32));

INSERT INTO post_meta VALUES
  (468, '_product_id', 432),
  (468, '_user_id', 1),
  (468, '_status', 'active'),
  (469, '_product_id', 432),
  (469, '_user_id', 1),
  (469, '_status', 'active');

SELECT post_id, GROUP_CONCAT(IF(meta_key='_product_id', meta_value,'') SEPARATOR '') _product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(IF(meta_key='_status', meta_value,'') SEPARATOR '') _status FROM post_meta WHERE post_id = 468 AND meta_key IN ('_product_id', '_status') GROUP BY post_id;
```

Regards,

James

Comment: This returned an empty result set for me. However, I was able to tweak this a little and get a working result set. My issue now is I can't get a working where or having clause. Would you please take a look at my edited post?

Comment: Have you solved this now or do you want me to try with your answers query? If so is the.

Comment: (fat fingers...) is the $user pseudocode? If not why the $ prefix? Surely it should be @ right?

Comment: $user is a PHP variable that is defined before the query is ran. There were a few issues with your query. The first being that I'm not trying to find the results where post_id = 468. 468 refers to a specific order. I am trying to find all orders where product_id = 432 and the status = 'active' and user = $user (the currently logged in user defined before the query). Your query returned an empty array. I experimented a bunch and found some other SO answers along with your help that allowed me to come up with the right solution which I answered below.